# Cannot use my account with Microsoft graph explorer

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Somehow I'm unable to login to the Graph Explorer to test the Microsoft Graph Office APIs on my account that works fine on MSDN. I get a 'bad request' error after login. How come?

Comment: Stack overflow i for programming. This is not a programming question

Comment: Microsoft graph is an API. The P in that acronym makes this question relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use the actual Graph API with both personal accounts as well as Office 365 accounts you actually can only use the Graph Explorer with Office 365 accounts. Your MSDN account is probably not an Office 365 account. For testing purposes you can get a free trial [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=510938&culture=nl-NL&country=NL).

Comment: We are working on enabling the Graph Explorer to use with consumer accounts as well. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Yina I have an Office365 account (access to Yammer, O365 products) but I can't use the graph explorer. I get that error `Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 45dc7e2b-b2a0-4178-8bf6-a0e23da0c36a
Timestamp: 2016-06-27 22:01:40Z
AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.`

Comment: The update that Yina is describing will also help to alleviate the problem you are running  in to.  Today graph explorer requests permissions to your tenant's data up front, including some highly privileged permissions that only a tenant admin may consent to. The error above (which we are also working on) indicates that you are signed in, in a regular user role and hence not allowed to consent.  Future versions of Graph Explorer will allow you to incrementally consent to access your data, without requiring consent to highly privileged permissions. Hope this helps!